# Problems with the line number and inputs

Tags: python, line

This is going to be hard to describe but I am going to do my best lol. Hopefully it is a simple enough problem that you understand it fairly easily. The problem comes in at the `if input() = ('x')` part. Python is wanting the user to push 1 on line 21, 2 on line 23, 3 on line 25, etc... What I WANT Python to do is let me press 1 when on line 20, where it says ('Enter a number:')

```
import random,time,sys

next_scene = '1'

def q():
    print('What do you do?')

def scene_0():
    return 0

def scene_1():
    print('The errie screech of an old cieling fan wakes you. Your eyes open to see a small room, lit only by a dark red lightbulb hanging in the center of the room. You sit up on the ground and analyze your few surroundings. The only thing that catches your eye is a large metal door across from you. The air is cold, and the silence is only broken by your breathing and the fan.')
    q()
    print('1. Stay sitting and wait')
    print('2. Investigate the door')
    print('3. Bang on the door and scream')
    print('4. Fall back asleep')
    print('5. Study the fan')

    choice = input('Enter a number:') 
    if input() == '1':
        scene_2()
    elif input() == '2':
        scene_3()
    elif input() == '3':
        scene_4()
    elif input() == '4':
        scene_5()
    elif input() == '5':
        scene_6()
    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Enter a number:')
    return choice

def scene_2():
    print('You stay sitting on the concrete ground. The air is cold, and the silence is just as heavy. You begin searching your memory, hoping for anything that would answer the question of why you are here, however, you do not even know where you are. As you sit in thought, you are interuppted by a loud metal sliding, and about ten seconds after that, a much louder SLAM. After the slam, you hear the echo of somoene stepping closer, before the metal sliding, ten seconds, and the SLAM again.')
    q()
    print('1. Stand up and watch the door.')
    print('2. Stay sitting.')
    print('3. Hide in the corner.')

    choice = input('Enter a number: ')

    return choice

def scene_3():
     print('You approach the door and put your hands to it. It is incredibly thick, and cold to the touch. You can\'t even feel the door move at all.')
     q()
     print('1. Bang on the door and scream.')
     print('2. Go back to the other side of the room')

def scene_4():
    print('You run to the door and begin to bang on it with both your hands. The bangs reverberate around your room, and you scream as lound as you can trying to get any sound through the door that you can. The door is thick and heavy, and it hardly moves even while you hit it as hard as you can.')

def scene_5():
    print('You don\'t know where you are, but there is no diseranble threat. There is nothing you can do, except sleep. \n  You rest for what feels to be about fifteen minutes, however, you are awoken by the opening of the door across from where you slept')

def scene_6():
    print('The fan appears to be incredibly old, and even the bottom of the blades is covered in dust. You can absolutely see the blade that is the loudest, as it is slightly bent. The fan is only about a foot above you, with a good jump you could even grab it.')




scene_1()
```

Comment: Why do you keep calling `input` so many times when you already have `choice` ?

Comment: If your `if/elif` statements, replace `input()` with `choice`.  You've already asked for the input, reuse that.

Comment: When I change the input() to choice it gives me a 'str' object is not callable. While it is input() it works, just works weird.

Comment: @Elsen, don't add `()` after `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

The `input` method wait to read from the user, you used it well here     `choice = input('Enter a number:')` but you're calling it again in the condition `if input() == '1':`, don't.

```
choice = input('Enter a number:')
if choice == '1':
    scene_2()
elif choice == '2':
    scene_3()
elif choice == '3':
    scene_4()
elif choice == '4':
    scene_5()
elif choice == '5':
    scene_6()
else:
    print('Invalid answer. Enter a number:')
return choice
```

Comment: Whenever I change all of them to choice it gives me str error, whenever I used input it at least worked, just worked weird. When I change them to choice it says 'str' object is not callable

Comment: right now my code looks like this
choice = input('Enter a number:') 
    if choice() == '1':
        scene_2()
    elif choice() == '2':
        scene_3()
    elif choice() == '3':
        scene_4()
    elif choice() == '4':
        scene_5()
    elif choice() == '5':
        scene_6()
    else:
        print('Invalid answer. Enter a number:')
    return choice
and it is giving me the 'str' error